# Using regular expressions in conditional expressions in Postgresql v.9.6

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column I denote with "col" containing character values. I would like to extract a column such that at the position where the column "col" starts with either '01', '02' or '03' the column will have the value "yes" and otherwise "no". I tried with the following code and can't get it to work.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN col ~ '^(01|02|03)' THEN 'yes'
ELSE 'no' END
FROM table;
```

I know that one solution is to use the LIKE operator in the following way, but I am looking for a more compact way to solve this.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN col LIKE '01%' THEN 'yes'
WHEN col LIKE '02%' THEN 'yes'
WHEN col LIKE '03%' THEN 'yes'
ELSE 'no' END
FROM table;
```

Any solution, even without regular expression, would be very helpful.

Thanks // Henri

Comment: Your first code works when I try it.

Comment: Oh, how strange! Then I know that it can't be the code that is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: what's the exact error?.. what problem you hit?..